# SoapUI: Transfer Response Payload Value to New Request URL (Different Test Steps)

Tags: json, properties, soapui, transfer

I'm trying to figure out SoapUI, and so far it's been a great tool. However, I cannot figure out this transferring of property stuff. I've read so much and just can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I have one request: POST http://localhost/restaurant

I receive the following Response Payload back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 22:50:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 35

    {
      "supplementalInfo":null,
      "id":1146
    }
```

I then want to take the "id" value and place it in the following request: DELETE http://localhost/restaurant/{id}

I've tried: /restaurant/${Create A New Restaurant#Response#//*:id} WHERE "Create A New Restaurant" is the name of the Test Step where the response payload is from to no avail.

What am I missing? Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried creating a property transfer test step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Response from "Create A New Restaurant" is `application/json`, but you are using the XPath (XML) notation to transfer the value! That is not going to work.

Luckily, SoapUI internally converts *almost* anything to XML representation. To get at that, you will need to use: `${Create A New Restaurant#ResponseAsXml#//*:id}`. Note the extra "AsXml" in there.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much; I completely glossed over the JSON/XML difference,